# How does node js session data work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Example: I have an API which returns `JSON` for a user profile that's requested via HTTP. But the thing is I'm going to need the user who's requesting the profile via http's `userId and auth token` to verify if the users profile they've requested is a friend of theres.

Is it as easy as storing the data in a module like so? Or are there guidelines that you're suppose to follow when doing this? Or am I thinking about node the wrong way?

#### Module: user.js

Once the user has logged in and the data has been added to the user:

```
module.export = {
    userId: 20111,
    authToken: "HDaj3916s8s4b17",   
    loggedIn: true,
    username: "testUser15"
}
```

#### Module: app.js

```
 // Create a new chat
    router.route('/user-profile/').get(function(req, res) {
    connection.connect();
         if(user.userId == "" || user.authToken == "")
               return false; 

         // Requires userId and authToken to validate
         if(checkToSeeIfFriends(user.userId, user.authToken)){
              return USER_PROF_DATA;
         } else{ console.log("Not friends"); }
    });
```

Up for a discussion or a straight up answer! Btw, I'm pretty new to node.

Comment: Strongly recommend you to use a mature framework like `express` to handle sessions for you.

Comment: Using this package? - https://github.com/expressjs/session @TwilightSun

Comment: Yes, that's the middleware to use if you're using `express`, and you may want to pick a suitable session store so the session data won't be lost when you restart the app.

Comment: @TwilightSun Would something like `redis` be suitable for storing values like usernames, id's, and other bits of data that may be handy to have?

Comment: Redis would be fine, and its quite popular for storing session values because it provides reasonable performance and is much easier to scale than many other stores when you need to add load balancing. Just don't expose the redis server port to public network if you're working on something serious.